# How to pronounce unaspirated stop sound properly? Such as the /t/ in " let me", is it just/lɛ/ /mi/?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, consonants

I'm not a native speaker, and I feel difficult to pronounce unaspirated stop sound properly, such as the /t/ in "let me". I found some learning materials on internet, but they are not sophisticated about the process of pronounce unaspirated stop sound. In "let me", the /t/ is unaspirated, so as materials said, I should close the mouth and block the air stream after /lɛ/, until meet /m/ in "me", then release the air stream. I don't know whether is that right or not. I'm very confused.

Answer (score 2):

It might depend on what accent you're trying to emulate.

For me, Northern Br E, the 'close' is at the back of the tongue to the throat.
If I emulate a generic Southern Br E or US E it seems to be further forward, but it's still tongue, not lips.
The move to the 'm' of 'me' is a separate move.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I fell sorry about that I forgot to check my question until today. I want to emulate US E accent, and I feel difficult to make a 'close' at the back of the tongue, but I feel easier to make it at the front of the tongue. I'm wondering whether it matters or not.

Comment: It matters because it changes the 'accent' quite considerably. For US Eng you can think of it more like a 'd' but without the follow-on, simply a stop.

Comment: I understood, but I have another related question. Is this kind of 'stop' same with glottal T?

Comment: Not in US E; but it is in Northern Br E. It all depends on the accent.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. English is really hard for non-native speakers to learn!